# What's the correct form of the negative subjunctive?

Tags: grammar, negation, subjunctive-mood, subordinate-clauses, mandative-subjunctive

> It is essential that [some parameter] be not reset during the day. (1)
>
> It is essential that [some parameter] not be reset during the day. (2)

Which one is the correct form? I do know the easy way out, that is:

> It is essential that [some parameter] is not reset during the day. (3)

But which is the correct form provided I want to stick with the subjunctive?

Comment: option (2), "*not be*" is correct.

Comment: Would _It is essential to not reset [some parameter] during the day_ work for you?

Comment: **be not reset** is what is trying to be conveyed in the context. Although both could nearly mean the same, the verb and the negation have specific functions in this sentence. The sentence structure would be different if you say "Do not reset ..." instead.

Comment: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+this+not+be+done%2Cthat+this+be+not+done&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthat%20this%20not%20be%20done%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20this%20be%20not%20done%3B%2Cc0) shows that somewhere around 1950, the preferred order changed from *be not reset* to *not be reset*. Some comments. (1) I checked the hits, and they almost all are subjunctives. (2) They are also almost all American. I have no idea which order is preferred in the U.K. (although maybe they prefer that the subjunctive not be used).

Comment: @PeterShor It's perilous to use nGrams in such cases. Both versions are correct in every respect, but emphasize on different things, the difference may be subtle but very important here.

Comment: I also second "not be" in this context.

Comment: @mplungjan: It most certainly would, as would option (3), but I am interested in the grammatical aspect here.

Comment: @Kris: you replied when I was halfway though writing my comment. I believe I've addressed your question in it. It's hard to believe that these are two constructions meaning two different things when all the pre-1920 subjunctive uses are *be not done* and almost all the post-1960 uses are *not be done*. What do you perceive as the difference between them? Do you have any evidence for this?

Comment: All 3 are grammatically correct, which I think was your question. That said, the other comments are appropriate, and I too second *not be reset*.

Comment: @PeterShor: I think we Brits prefer the subjunctive *to be avoided*, rather than that the subjunctive *not be used*.

Comment: @FF So, *'It is essential that [some parameter] not is reset during the day.'

Comment: Somebody please answer the question.  @DanBron I am talking to you.  :-)

Comment: @CyberHerbalist, would that I could, but I can't justify my position. To paraphrase Justice Potter: I can't define good grammar, but I know it when I see it ;)

Comment: Sometimes, @DanBron, the comments are more interesting than the question OR the answer.  This is one of those times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As many proposed in comments, and given that we live many years after 1960, I would also say "not be". :-)

EDIT: 
My response actually meant that people who use a language know what form to use intuitively. Language evolves and if at some point *in time* the majority of English speakers tend to say "not be" rather than "be not", that's what the grammar book will adopt.

The question regards the acceptable form of the negative subjunctive. Examples can be found e.g. here:

http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/subjunctive.html

and here:

http://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/subjunctive

Both sources agree on "not be".

Comment: Apologies for the joking mood. That cost me some reputation! The date is important. Thou must agree that I cannot say "thou" instead of "you"! I am posting a link which describes the negative subjunctive, I am sure grammar books have similar examples.