# How to use a "not" while requesting?

Tags: grammar, expressions, expression-choice

I am getting confused to use a "not" while requesting. e.g.
`I request you not to think in this way`. I am not sure whether it is correct? But, I need to be clear how to use "not" in such situations.

Comment: Please don’t think that way.

Comment: That's ok @tchrist and thank you for your answer. So can we use a "not" with request as in my example?

Comment: What you have written there is not grammatical in my language. It may be so in others. *I request that you not do that* is grammatical for me  but also so miserably stuffy I can't imagine being taken seriously if I said it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems you're running into is that you're request should take the form of a [mandative subjunctive](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/197130/58761). If you're stuck on theis form, properly it looks like

> I request you *not think* in this way.

Which is a strange request out of context. Some other examples which might be more helpful:

> - I request that you *not be* hasty in your appraisal.
> - I request that you *not be* late for this class.
> - I request that I *not be contacted* via email, snail mail, or any other correspondence provided by your firm.
> - I request that they *not be identified* to any of these individuals.

Etc. In other words, am, are, is are replaced by *be*.

It's usually easier to just not use the subjunctive negative.

> - Please *do not* contact me with any further offers.
> - Please *do not* be late for this class.
> - Please *do not* be negative in your thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please think in a different way?

I think you just need to rephrase if you want to avoid the word "not" in your sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I request that you avoid using *not* in requests.

Answer (score -1):

If I were to change your sentence, I'd say "I request you to *not* think in this way". I think "I request you to" seems like a single clause, and I'd not put a 'not' in the middle of that phrase.

But I'm not quite sure what you are asking here besides the placement of the word "not". Could you clarify?

Comment: I am getting confused when using a "not" in such sentences. As per my knowledge I can use a "not" only after a helping verb. But in my requested sentence, I can't get any helping verb until I change the sentence as suggested by @tchrist. (Please don't think)

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Answers on Stack Exchange should be more than simple opinion. "seems like a single clause" isn't terribly helpful. Can you provide any sources to back up this statement?